# R - adding P12 certificate to get call

Tags: r, httr, rcurl

I have a successful call in Postman where I access an API with a .p12 certificate. In Postman, the certificate is stored in the global settings.

Now I am trying to translate this Postman-call to R-code, where I spent hours playing around using the `httr` and `rCURL` packages. Unfortunately, without results where my call results in a 403 (no valid certificate).

**My steps:**

First, I defined my headers for my call and the url

```
headers = c(
  'Content-Type' = 'application/pdf',
  'Authorization' = 'Basic ...'
) 

#Set URL
url = "https://myurlwithcertificate.eu"
```

Next I linked to my .p12 certificate

```
#Cert info
pkcs12_name <- "certi.p12"
pkcs12_pwd <- "certificatePassword"
```

I tried to perform the call:

```
res <- httr::GET(url = url, 
             add_headers(headers),
             config = config(sslcert=pkcs12_name,
                             sslkey=pkcs12_pwd))
```

Leading into: `could not load PEM client certificate`

Next I also tried to first use the `read_p12` function to open the certificate.

```
#Open certificate
cert <- read_p12(pkcs12_name,pkcs12_pwd)
```

I managed to successfully open the .p12 certificate. However, I didn't manage to add the certificate and the key in my call to the API.

```
res <- httr::GET(url = url, 
             add_headers(headers),
             config = config(sslcert=cert$cert,
                             sslkey=cert$key))
```

As a test, I have this call successfully created in Python. However, I also want to achieve the result in R.

**Python script:**

```
import requests
from requests_pkcs12 import get

url = "https://myurlwithcertificate.eu"

payload={}
headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/pdf',
  'Authorization': 'Basic ...'
}

response = get(url, headers = headers, data=payload, pkcs12_filename='certi.p12', pkcs12_password='certificatePassword')



response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

print(response.text)
```

I have the feeling that somehow in my R-script I didn't successfully managed to add the certificate in the call, url and headers are fine. Please if you have any ideas how I can manage to add the .p12 certificate in my call, let me know :)